# OData WCF Data Services - Related data (by foreign key) doesn't show up when calling the service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-2, wcf-data-services, odata

When I get the data using the URL in browser, I'm able to see the related data, for example:

http://localhost/services.svc/Dinners(1)/RSVPs

That lists 5 RSVPs for DinnerId = 1 in my case, but when I'm consuming the OData from a different project, I can only retrieve Dinners, debugging the app shows that RSVPs = 0, while it should be 5.

I'm consuming the service by adding a Service Reference to my project, and returning the data via a very simple LINQ query:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var result = (from d in db.Dinners
                          select d);

            return View(result);
        }
```

Any idea why d.RSVPs = 0 when it should be populated? I'm using EF (Code first - followed a post by ScottGu, with 2 very simple POCO classes for Dinner and RSVP. Dinner class have the collection of RSVPs: `public ICollection<RSVP> RSVPs { get; set; }`, and the RSVP class points to the Dinner with a foreign key `public int DinnerId { get; set; }` as well as the Dinner class: `public Dinner Dinner { get; set; }`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the problem is within the keyword `virtual` when I create the POCO classes with related tables. If I have the `virtual` keyword when referencing `ICollection<RSVP>` inside Dinner class or `Dinner` inside my RSVP class, lazy loading is enabled, but WCF Data Service stopped working! Taking the `virtual` keyword out and the WCF Data service started to work again, but then I don't have lazy/deferred loading enabled! I'm not sure if this is a feature or a bug?! For now, I guess I'll wait for the next release to really start using EF POCO and WCF Data Service.

Thanks all for looking.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Expand() to access more than one level of the returned object graph.

[Loading Deferred Content (WCF Data Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358709.aspx)

Something like:

```
var result = (from d in db.Dinners.Expand("RSVPs")
                      select d);
```

Comment: I was thinking about something similar after posted my question (Lazy loading?), but couldn't figure out the way. Using `Expand("RSVPs")` causes a different error: `Error processing response stream. Server failed with following message: An error occurred while processing this request.` Any idea why? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Saxman, the string needs to be the property name.  Please read the documentation and then try "RSVPs"

Comment: Hi jfar, that's what I did, I've used `"RSVPs"`, not `"RSVPS"`, also tried couple different combinations without success. :( Thanks.

Comment: Inner exception is null, it gave me error on my asp.net mvc code though, where I have the foreach loop: `<% foreach (var d in Model) { %>` . Accessing the generated Url directly in browser also gives me the same error: `http://localhost:60538/service.svc/Dinners()?$expand=RSVPs`.  Thanks for looking.

Comment: Set UserVerboseErrors to true gave me a better error: `at System.Data.Services.Serializers.SyndicationSerializer.WriteObjectProperties(IExpandedResult expanded, Object customObject, ResourceType resourceType, Uri absoluteUri, String relativeUri, SyndicationItem item, DictionaryContent content, EpmSourcePathSegment currentSourceRoot) at System.Data.Services.Serializers.SyndicationSerializer.WriteEntryElement(IExpandedResult expanded, Object element, ResourceType expectedType, Uri absoluteUri, String relativeUri, SyndicationItem target)`

Comment: This is working with small changes.
you save my time thank you.
var result = (from d in db.Dinners.Expand<RSVPs>(x => x.ForiegnKeyProperty)
                      select d);